# showing internet content on an intranet site

Tags: asp.net

I've an ASP.NET application hosted inside a local area network. The application host machine has access to the internet while the local area network clients do not.

There is one requirement where I've to show a web page with rich content (images) in an IFrame from internet (public network) address.

However since internet access is not available on the client, this somehow has to be done from server and then needs to be served to client.

How can this be done?

Comment: If they have no network connection how are they going to browse your site in the first place? And if the server has no network connection how is that going to serve your site?

Comment: With network connection I meant access to public network or internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` from your application's code to query another server, then you can re-serve it's response by ouputting it to `Response`. To replicate an actual web page, you'd further have to parse out all embedded resources (scripts, images, whatever) and request them from the host server again, and create an architecture so they could be re-streamed from your application. That is, if you simply regurgitated the response for a page request, none of the resources would load since the client wouldn't have access. You'll need to re-write those URLs in the page to something on your server that will then re-request them from the real server. Sounds like a pain to me, but technically doable.

I would think it a lot easier to create some kind of proxy that will allow your clients to access the the site directly through your portal. (What I'm proposing above is basically a specialized proxy). If you can work directly with IIS, you could create something that functioned as a more direct proxy for this purpose. I'm guessing there must be a good reason why you need to do this, like, these are public terminals at a retail store and you obviously don't want your customers price-shopping from there :)

Comment: Similar to some thing which I've thought. I was thinking there might be some website downloder like free api which might help me to download the pages locally. Writing a downloader like functionality is such a pain... and the cost is not worth the time and effort.

Comment: What I was getting at with creating a proxy of sorts is, you could create an ISAPI handler to intercept all requests to the site, and conditionally redirect them. So your code could serve up a page with a simple replacement of offsite resources to `someurl/originalurl/resource.xxx' - the handler would use 'someurl' to identify it as a proxy request and then redirect the request to the offsite server, capture the response, and stream it to the client. After deciding the offsite url is OK. I am sure there are details I haven't thought of but the basic implementation ought to be straightfoward.